# Cores dos nomes em um chat em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou começando a programar, e me surgiu um problema. Preciso desenvolver uma espécie de chat extremamente simples, apenas indicando o nome e a mensagem, sem comunicação com outros computadores, apenas aparecer o nome digitado e a mensagem. Porém preciso que cada nome receba uma cor aleatória e que sempre que o nome for o mesmo a cor seja a mesma também. Por exemplo: Luiz recebe a cor azul, sempre que o Luiz escrever algo seu nome estará em azul.

Segue abaixo os códigos html, css e javascript.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aula 09 - Chat</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="aula09-atividade.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aula09-atividade.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="principal">

        <div id="cabecalho">
            <h1 id="chat">CHAT</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="nomecss">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Nome">
        </div>

        <div id="mensagemcss">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id="botao">
            <button id="btEnviar" class="btn btn-danger">Enviar</button>
        </div>

        <div id="tabelacss">
            <table id="tabela"></table>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#principal{
    margin: 10px 120px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 520px;
    background: #086A87;
    border: 1px solid #A9D0F5;
}

#cabecalho{
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

#chat{
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#nomecss{
    width: 500px;
}

#mensagemcss textarea{
    width: 500px;
    height: 155px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    resize: none;
}

#tabelacss{
    display: block;
    background: white;
    height: 243px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    white-space: wrap;
    border: 1px solid #A9D0F5;
    clear: both;
}

#tabelacss td{
    display: inline;
}

#botao{
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function montarTabela(chat, nome, mensagem, id){
    var html = '';

    chat.push([ [nome] , [mensagem] ]);

    for(i = 0; i < chat.length; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            if(i == 0){
                chat[i][2] = gera_cor();
                break;
            }
            else if(chat[i][0] == chat[j][0]){
                chat[i][2] = chat[j][2];
                break;
            }
            else{
                chat[i][2] = gera_cor();
                break;
            }
        }

        html += "<tr>"+
                "<td style=color:" + chat[i][2] + ";><strong>" + chat[i][0] + "</strong></td>"+
                "<td><em> diz:  </em></td>"+
                "<td>" + chat[i][1] + "</td>"+
                "</tr>";
    }    

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
}



function gera_cor(){
    var hexadecimais = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var cor = '#';

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        cor += hexadecimais[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return cor;
}




document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    chat = [];

    document.getElementById("btEnviar").addEventListener("click", function(){

        var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
        var mensagem = document.getElementById("mensagem").value;

        //if (nome != "" && mensagem != "") {

            montarTabela(chat, nome, mensagem, "tabela");

            document.getElementById("mensagem").value = "";

        //}
        //else{
            //alert("Preencher todos os campos!");
        //}

    })

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está gerando novas cores para as que já existem no primeiro laço `for` (onde tem a variável `i`) da função `montarTabela()`. Com isso, cada vez que você montar a tabela, serão geradas novas cores, sobrescrevendo as existentes.

Minha sugestão é já fazer o push na array já com a cor definida. É só fazer um laço antes do laço que monta a tabela e verificar se já existe um nome igual ao que foi digitado, e se existir, pegar o valor da cor na array e inserir no novo item da array (veja explicações no código):

```js
function montarTabela(chat, nome, mensagem, id){
    var html = '';

    for(var j = 0; j < chat.length; j++){
       // verifica se o nome é igual ao da array
       if(nome == chat[j][0][0]) break;
    }

    // se já existe um nome igual, pega o mesmo valor da cor,
    // em chat[j][2]; se não, gera uma nova cor.
    // Se !chat.length (array vazia) ou
    // se o valor de "j" for igual ao tamanho da array,
    // significa que nada foi encontrado, então chama gera_cor()
    var cor = !chat.length || j == chat.length ? gera_cor() : chat[j][2];
   
    chat.push([ [nome] , [mensagem], cor ]);

    for(var i = 0; i < chat.length; i++){

        html += "<tr>"+
                "<td style=color:" + chat[i][2] + ";><strong>" + chat[i][0] + "</strong></td>"+
                "<td><em> diz:  </em></td>"+
                "<td>" + chat[i][1] + "</td>"+
                "</tr>";
    }    

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
    
}



function gera_cor(){
    var hexadecimais = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var cor = '#';

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        cor += hexadecimais[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return cor;
}




document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    chat = [];

    document.getElementById("btEnviar").addEventListener("click", function(){

        var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
        var mensagem = document.getElementById("mensagem").value;

        //if (nome != "" && mensagem != "") {

            montarTabela(chat, nome, mensagem, "tabela");

            document.getElementById("mensagem").value = "";

        //}
        //else{
            //alert("Preencher todos os campos!");
        //}

    })

})
```

```css
#principal{
    margin: 10px 120px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 520px;
    background: #086A87;
    border: 1px solid #A9D0F5;
}

#cabecalho{
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

#chat{
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#nomecss{
    width: 500px;
}

#mensagemcss textarea{
    width: 500px;
    height: 155px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    resize: none;
}

#tabelacss{
    display: block;
    background: white;
    height: 243px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    white-space: wrap;
    border: 1px solid #A9D0F5;
    clear: both;
}

#tabelacss td{
    display: inline;
}

#botao{
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">

  <div id="cabecalho">
      <h1 id="chat">CHAT</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="nomecss">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Nome">
  </div>

  <div id="mensagemcss">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div id="botao">
      <button id="btEnviar" class="btn btn-danger">Enviar</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tabelacss">
      <table id="tabela"></table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ajudou muito Sam, muito obrigado! Abraço.